# How to extend the translation?

Tags: sapui5

I extend a standard fiori application and I would like to extend **i18n** also.
The structure of the extended app looks as the following:

[image]

And in the **Component.js** file, I notice the extension:

```
this.i2d.eam.pmnotification.create.s1.Component.extend("i2d.eam.pmnotification.create.s1.ZEAM_NTF_CRES1_EXT.Component", {
    metadata: {
        manifest: "json",
        config: {
            "sap.ca.i18Nconfigs": {
                bundleName: "i2d.eam.pmnotification.create.s1.ZEAM_NTF_CRES1_EXT.i18n.i18n"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

but the text still does not get translated.

The content of the `i18n.properties` file:

```
ext.createNotification=Create notification
ext.createOrder=Create order
```

and Buttons, that are using the translation:

```
<Button press="onCreateWithOrder" text="{i18n>ext.createOrder}" />
<Button press="onSave" text="{i18n>ext.createNotification}"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only used "sap.ca.i18Nconfigs"with success when translating apps using the old fashion "scaffolding" namespace (sap.ca.scfld).

I would bet that the app you are extending is not based on it.

Then, try to add the following calls to your Component.js file

```
init: function() {
        UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
            bundleUrl: "../pathToYourParentApp/i18n/i18n.properties"
        });

        oModel.enhance({
            bundleUrl: "i18n/i18n.properties"
        });

        this.setModel(oModel, "i18n");
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "i18n");

    }
```

---

Also, check the example 
https://github.com/fabiopagoti/ui5-extension